# How to display ligands as ball and stick and macromolecules as cartoons (if protein) / rings (if nucleic acids) in Avogadro?

Tags: software

Avogadro has many good qualities but I can't seem to find a way to display ligands differently to macromolecules in the same view window. Frankly I can't seem to find a way to display any two things differently (like one as ball and stick, another as ribbons, or w/e) to one another in the same view. It seems like in a given view window everything has to be displayed the same way, there's no room for making one part displayed one way and another part displayed another way.

Answer (score 1):

This was also asked on the [Avogadro discussion forum](https://discuss.avogadro.cc/t/how-to-display-ligands-as-ball-and-stick-and-macromolecules-as-cartoons-if-protein-rings-if-nucleic-acids-in-avogadro/2722?u=ghutchis)

It's possible in Avogadro 1.x and discussed in the [documentation](https://avogadro.cc/docs/display-types/coloring-part-of-a-molecule/)

- Select part of the molecule
- Click on the "options" button for a particular display type (e.g. "ball and stick")
- Click on the button to only show the selected atoms

[image]